Background video not loading on any mobile phones
So here is my code:
  <!-- VIDEO OVERLAY-->
  <div class="video_overlay">
    <header>
      <!-- This div is  intentionally blank. It creates the transparent black overlay over the video which you can modify in the CSS -->
      <div class="overlay"></div>

      <!-- The HTML5 video element that will create the background video on the header -->
      <video playsinline autoplay loop muted id="video-background" poster="/images/cover.jpg">
         <!--<source src="/video/nmvg_intro_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />-->
        
        <source src="/video/nmvg_intro_2.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"'>
        <source src="/video/nmvg_intro_2.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
        <source src="/video/nmvg_intro_2.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>

      <!-- The header content -->
      <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="d-flex h-100 text-center align-items-center">
          <div class="w-100 text-white">
            <h1 class="display-3">my text here</h1>
            <p class="lead mb-0">my test</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <!-- VIDEO OVERLAY OVER-->

On desktop there is no issue, even on very low speed internet video loads just fine but on any mobile browser: Firefox, Mull, Chrome, Chromium, Chromite, Tor, Bromite etc etc its just shows blank screen.
I tried with data saver disabled, phone charged to 100%
Some of the answers suggested interactions so i even tried that, loaded website on phone and then click home page to initiate interaction still no joy. even the poster is not loading even though its url is correct
Here is my properties of the video from Debugger
Strange thing is that in chrome debugger's mobile mode, on reloading sometime video is shown in network tab nut it just 12ms and never completed, but on most of 99% reload it just never shows up. for eg:
my debugger network view
accessKey
: 
""
attributeStyleMap
: 
StylePropertyMap {size: 0}
attributes
: 
NamedNodeMap {0: src, 1: type, src: src, type: type, length: 2}
autocapitalize
: 
""
autofocus
: 
false
baseURI
: 
"https://patriboarding.org/index.html"
childElementCount
: 
0
childNodes
: 
NodeList []
children
: 
HTMLCollection []
classList
: 
DOMTokenList [value: '']
className
: 
""
clientHeight
: 
0
clientLeft
: 
0
clientTop
: 
0
clientWidth
: 
0
contentEditable
: 
"inherit"
dataset
: 
DOMStringMap {}
dir
: 
""
draggable
: 
false
elementTiming
: 
""
enterKeyHint
: 
""
height
: 
0
hidden
: 
false
id
: 
""
inert
: 
false
innerHTML
: 
""
innerText
: 
""
inputMode
: 
""
isConnected
: 
true
isContentEditable
: 
false
lang
: 
""
localName
: 
"source"
media
: 
""
namespaceURI
: 
"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling
: 
source
nextSibling
: 
text
nodeName
: 
"SOURCE"
nodeType
: 
1
nonce
: 
""
offsetHeight
: 
0
offsetLeft
: 
0
offsetTop
: 
0
offsetWidth
: 
0
outerHTML
: 
"<source src=\"/video/nmvg_intro_2.webm\" type=\"video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp8.0, vorbis&quot;\">"
outerText
: 
""
ownerDocument
: 
document
parentElement
: 
video#video-background
parentNode
: 
video#video-background
part
: 
DOMTokenList [value: '']
previousSibling
: 
text
scrollHeight
: 
0
scrollLeft
: 
0
scrollTop
: 
0
scrollWidth
: 
0
sizes
: 
""
slot
: 
""
spellcheck
: 
true
src
: 
"https://patriboarding.org/video/nmvg_intro_2.webm"
srcset
: 
""
style
: 
CSSStyleDeclaration {accentColor: '', additiveSymbols: '', alignContent: '', alignItems: '', alignSelf: '', …}
tabIndex
: 
-1
tagName
: 
"SOURCE"
textContent
: 
""
title
: 
""
translate
: 
true
type
: 
"video/webm; codecs=\"vp8.0, vorbis\""
virtualKeyboardPolicy
: 
""
width
: 
0
writingSuggestions
: 
"true"

Please help I am at my wits end
Here is the size of all my 3 videos which are self hosted on hostinger:
size of all my 3 video formats
I tired adding playsinline autoplay loop muted
I tired the website interaction by clicking on homepage again to load the website
I set the mobile browsers on non data saver non throttling modes

Ideally, your question should include a working example so people don’t need to visit your website. Looking at your website, you have a style @media (pointer: coarse) and (hover: none) { header video {display: none;}} that’s disabling the video on mobile devices.

Ok am not that good on css so where should I be going to disable this?

You can use your browser’s developer tools to see the CSS style that are being applied to your page. You will need to use the mobile emulation mode to see the styles that are applied to a mobile device. The styles for the mobile browser are in the custom.css file (there is a URL for a background image for mobile devices, but the URL isn’t valid). If you’re not sure how to use the developer tools, there are plenty of tutorials on YouTube.
